# Microbatching with partition by and .set-or-append kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to copy a large amount of data (over 70 million rows) from 1 table to another. I am having trouble because .set-or-append is timing out even when I microbatch manually. I am willing to bet there is some microbatch size in terms of rows that will allow the .set-or-append to succeed, but my problem is programatically delegating these microbatches to the .set-or-append command. This is what I have so far:

```
.set-or-append async MyTargetTable <|
let relevantIds= SourceTableName
| summarize innerCount=count() by __id
| where innerCount >= 5000
| top 10000 by innerCount desc;
SourceTableName
| where __id in (relevantIds)
| extend bucket = hash(row_number(), 10)
| partition by bucket
// unsure from here
```

The hashing function in kusto is great. I ran a basic query by ranging between 1...70 million in and seeing what the distribution of the hash function was for 10 buckets, and it was roughly 7 million each. I would like to utilize this function in order to create my partitioning. Essentially, this allows my microbatches to be roughly evenly sized, and then I can easily programatically increase the number of buckets if the microbatches fail.

My problem is that the partition by operator requires a subquery, and you cannot pass .set-or-append as a subquery to partition by. So I am unsure how I can utilize partition by operator with .set-or-append.

How can I split my data into 10 buckets (or N buckets) of roughly equal size (based on number of rows) and send that programitically to .set-or-append?

One more thing: since the .set-or-append returns an operation id, it would be great to get a list of operation ids for the microbatches that were queued up

EDIT: I saw a related question and tried to model my query after his, would something like this work?:

```
.set-or-append TargetTable <|
let _Scope = () {
    let relevantIds= SourceTable
    | summarize innerCount=count() by __id
    | where innerCount >= 5000
    | top 10000 by innerCount desc;
    let cachedIds = materialize(relevantIds);
    let BUCKETS = 10;
    range bucket from 0 to BUCKETS - 1 step 1
    | partition by bucket
    {
        SourceTable
        | where __id in (cacheIds)
        | where hash(row_number(), BUCKETS) == toscalar(bucket)
    }
};
union (_Scope())
```

what do you think? would this queue up 10 async ingestion operations partitioned by row number?

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned correctly - you can't invoke a control command (e.g. `.set-or-append`) from a query (regardless of whether or not that query uses the `partition` operator).

in order to copy large tables you could either:

1. [export the data to cloud storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/export-data-to-storage), then ingest it from blobs using the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/) / tools like [ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/data-factory-integration) / [LightIngest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/lightingest)
2. orchestrate a set of `.set-or-append` commands, where each handles a subset of the source data, up to ~1M records per command

- you could 'partition' the source data set using any filter that makes sense WRT your data set.
- compared to option 1, this option is somewhat more complex.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer! I am aware of lightingest and will look into that if needed. I also tried option 2, but since the query timesout because of number of rows needed to be ingested, it would be great to programatically queue up .set-or-appends. Do you think the command in my edit will work?

Comment: you don't need to "manually" partition the data set, if you use the `distributed` option of `.set-or-append` - see the docs. That said, as mentioned in the answer, handling 10s of millions of records in a single command is less preferred - and you should seriously consider option #1 in the answer - exporting the data, then ingesting from cloud storage

Comment: does the .export command for exporting to a blob support a very large amount of data (70 million+ but potentially 1 billion)?

Comment: as previously mentioned, you should 'partition' the data set such that each command handles a subset of the source data. for larger data sets, if you have the option to 'replay' the data set from its origin, you should consider doing _that_